# Call cordova plugin in extend js file

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

My cordova js plugin

```
function Push() {
};

Push.prototype.send = function(jsonParam, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Push", "send", [jsonParam])
};

Push.install = function() {
    if(!window.plugins) {
        window.plugins = {};
    }

    window.plugins.push = new Push();
    return window.plugins.push;
};

cordova.addConstructor(Push.install);
```

I call it in tag script inside html and work ok, but I wrap code into extend js file and link this file to html, it throw error.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined", source: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js (4)
```

I call like this

```
window.plugins.push.send(param, function(a){console.log('call success: '+a);}, function(f){alert('call error: '+f);});
```

Please help me to call plugin inside extend js file.

//////////// EDIT /////////////////////////

I think I know problem, I call push plugin inside method has param and I need pass push plugin as param too.

Comment: Can you change name of Push to something else like myPush or customPush? and try